# Apache Spark Mllib Fp-growth Function not found Java

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I'm new with spark, and I want to use the Fp Growth found in Mllib with java and maven. But I get this error during the compilation:

```
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] /home/cjd/fpgexample/src/main/java/org/fpgexample/FpgTest.java:[25,7] cannot find symbol
 symbol:   class Function
 location: class org.fpgexample.FpgTest
```

this are the imports and the error line:

```
package org.fpgexample;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowthModel;    
JavaRDD<List<String>> transactions = data.map( new Function<String, List<String>>() {`
```

I update the maven compiler to the 3.3 (using JDK 1.7), and spark-core and mllib 2.11 (1.5.1) versions. (with the mllib 2.10 1.4 maven didn't recognize the fpm.AssociationRules).

EDIT: I changed the maven compiler, pom.xml and JDK to 1.8 from 1.7, but the error persist.

Comment: The Function data type was added in Java 8, so you will need JDK 1.8.

Comment: oh, thank you, gonna try that and see.

Comment: Didn't work, i updated maven, the pom.xml and the jdk to 1.8, yet obtained the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the correct package as below:

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;